# Kafka streams - grouping by value property?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream that comes in with:

```
Key: { "Symbol": "xxx" }
Value: { "Date": "2019-01-01", ... }
```

So, I want to group by Symbol and then Value.Date in 5 day blocks. I.e. 01-01 -> 01-05.

```
KStream<Key, Value> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream(...);

stream.groupBy((key, value) -> key.getSymbol())
```

So I've got the stream properly, and the first step, I group by the Key.Symbol. Not really sure where to go from here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom timestamp extractor to returns the timestamp from the value, i.e., implement `TimestampExtractor` interface and specify your class via `default.timestamp.extractor` configuration parameter (cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#default-timestamp-extractor)

This allows you to use tumbling time windows based on the extracted timestamp via:

```java
groupBy(...).windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(5))).aggregate(...)
```

See the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#tumbling-time-windows